# VBS script to bring program to front

Tags: button, vbscript, click, window

I am writing VBS code to open Internet Explorer and go to www.google.com However when I run the program, it opens and navigates to www.yahoo.com but the internet explorer is NOT the front window. Can anyone help me with this? Is there a code I can use to bring internet explorer to the front? Thank you all! Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
 Dim ie


Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

ie.Navigate("wwww.yahoo.com")
```

One last question - Is there a code I can use to click a certain button that - specifically one that I can't get to by pressing "tab"?

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "http://www.yahoo.com/"
Do While ie.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop
ie.Visible = True
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate ie.document.title
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. It activated the app, but didn't make it appear. :(

Answer (score 2):

I have found that setting the Visible property to True ***after*** calling the AppActivate method works @daniel-cook.

Therefore, simply swapping the last 2 lines in @ansgar-wiechers' example produces the desired result.

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Navigate "http://www.yahoo.com/"
Do While ie.Busy : WScript.Sleep 100 : Loop
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate ie.document.title
ie.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

This works on my computer it opens IE and loads www.google.com:

```
Dim oShell
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.Run ("iexplore www.google.com")
```

As for your last question... probably, but you'd need to be more specific and should probably ask in a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `wscript.sleep()` function. Should work because this worked on notepad.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).